# Mockito: Verify a method is called at a specific point

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose calling `bar()` on a `Foo` object will in turn call `baz()` on its `Waldo` object, only in the first time. In other words,

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setWaldo(new Waldo());
foo.bar(); // This calls baz() on the Waldo.
foo.bar(); // This should not call baz() on the Waldo.
```

This is how I verify the call on `baz()` at the moment.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Waldo waldo = mock(Waldo.class);
foo.setWaldo(waldo);
foo.bar();
foo.bar();
verify(waldo).baz();
```

The problem with this is it doesn't verify when `baz()` was called. This would get a pass even if `baz()` gets called the second time `foo.bar()` is called.

How would verify this properly with Mockito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Waldo waldo = mock(Waldo.class);
foo.setWaldo(waldo);
foo.bar();
verify(waldo).baz();
foo.bar();
verifyNoMoreInteractions(waldo);
```